# Are different clock rates affecting the transfer-rate?

Tags: tcp, network, cpu

I have to kinds of IoT-devices, which should communicate over TCP and sharing files with each others.

IoT-device of type 1 has 240 MHz.

IoT-device of type 2 has 160 MHz.

Now I have observed the following behavior:

If type1 sends data via TCP to type1: needs 1 seconds

If type2 sends data via TCP to type2: needs 2 seconds

If type1 sends data via TCP to type2: needs 2 seconds

but:
If type2 sends data via TCP to type1: needs 3 seconds.

Is there any logical explaination for this?
When my 160MHz-device sends data to a 240MHz-device it need more time, than sending data from-160MHz-to-160MHz or from-240MHz-to-160MHz?

Comment: There are many variables in sending data and achievable throughput - CPU clock rates aren't usually among them unless the throughput maxes out memory bandwidth or CPU processing capability - all of which are off-topic here.

Comment: As Zac rightly pointed,There are lot of variables for sending the data and more importantly to deliver the payload without CRC. For example,CRC counter,Resource Allocation,SINR etc. I would suggest you to get the L1 traces and statistics to get a clear picture.